# Can't set minimum input date in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this two date pickers

```
<label>Check-In Date : . </label>
<input id="date1" type="date" name="from" required min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>">

<label>Check-Out Date : . </label>
<input id="date2" type="date" name="to" required onclick="setDate2();">
```

and a javascript

```
function setDate2() {
  var date=$('#date1').val().split('-');
  var day=date[2];
  var month=date[1]-1;
  var year=date[0];
  var someDate = new Date(year, month, day);

  someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 1); 
  var dd = someDate.getDate();
  var mm = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = someDate.getFullYear();

  var someFormattedDate = y + '-'+ mm + '-'+ dd;

  document.getElementById('date2').min = someFormattedDate;
  alert(document.getElementById('date2').min)
}
```

this code works fine but, `document.getElementById('date2').min = someFormattedDate;` doesn't seen to work or something? I'm getting the correct output but doesn't set the minimum value of `date2`...

Comment: `someFormattedDate;` probably isn't what you think it is. There's no initial value set on the first datepicker, so `$('#date1').val()` returns an empty string unless you first chose a value in that datepicker.

Comment: I've checked it with `alert(someFormattedDate)` and it give the right output

Comment: doesn't seem to work too... I've tried this ` document.getElementById('date2').min =  document.getElementById('date1').value`  and it worked, the problem right there is i need to add day on the value of date1

Comment: @jayrbayog What browser do you use? In Chrome it seems to work as expected.

Comment: im using chrome

Comment: did you just tried it? is it possible the version of my chrome is preventing it?

Comment: Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iStyx/6x1zb2fq/

Comment: yah, that works but when i tried `document.getElementById('date2').min = someFormattedDate;`  it doesn't work again..

Comment: @jayrbayog Yeah, I get it, I'll add answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
var someFormattedDate = y + '-' + mm + '-'+ dd;
```

You forgot that month or day could be one-digit number, so it should be like this:

```
var someFormattedDate = y + '-' + (mm<10?'0':'') + mm + '-' + (dd<10?'0':'') + dd;
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iStyx/6x1zb2fq/

**Added:** I'd like to recommend to use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library for date/time manipulations.